# Shotwell player for videos, how to configure this?

Tags: video, shotwell

I am using Shotwell 0.30.14 "Calle" on Ubuntu 20.04. I have images and videos in my collection. Double-clicking a video is supposed to play it, but it simply doesn't, it just does nothing.

The same videos, and all other videos as well, open happily in VLC from Nautilus.

I guess, if I could configure the path or the app name for the default video player in Shotwell, that would be great, but a lot of searching did not give any useful results.

How can I restore the default video player in Shotwell, or to configure a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this I did

```
SHOTWELL_LOG=1 SHOTWELL_LOG_FILE=:console: shotwell
```

which showed a strange message, including:

```
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/reg.exe: No such file or directory
```

It happens that Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is getting in the way. I just uninstalled the wslu package and shotwell started opening videos with the Nautilus default for the file type.